# Which is the top total tax-revenue increase in the Western World since the Great Depression?

Tags: taxes, history, economy

I am interested in knowing about the biggest increases in the total tax revenue as a percentage of the GDP. Total includes everything. In particular it includes: direct and indirect, federal, regional, state, local, etc.

Roosevelt raised the US tax revenue as a percentage of GDP in the 1930s. This was supposedly done by increasing taxes to the richest people and stimulating demand through public spending. During the WWII, tax-revenues increased a lot in the US.

**Are there more significant or recent examples in Europe, North-America, or (perhaps recently) in Latin-America?**

**Note:** This question is asking for very specific information: top tax-revenue increases in the Western World since the [Great Depression](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Depression).

Comment: Well the first tax over 0 would have been an infinite % increase over the previous rate

Comment: @Chad - I'm not sure without digging but FDR's increase was likely similar to that in concept (e.g. staring with extreme low)

Comment: @Chad Good point, although taxation goes back to the ancient Egypt (thousand years before Christ) and the classical Greece (see  Adams, Charles; For Good and Evil: The Impact of Taxes on the Course of Civilization).

Comment: @Chad Can you mention any nation without ANY tax throughout history?

Comment: @DVK Are you meaning that FDR's increase is the largest to your knowledge?

Comment: @Chad The question can be answered in a few paragraphs. It only admits ONE CORRECT answer. I have limited the question to the Western World and after the Great Depression, even though it was totally fine as it was.

Comment: @Drake - Babylon pre hammurabi,  The native american tribes, the tribes in the Amazon, the Inca, The aztec, the Vikings

Comment: The World Bank collects this data [Tax Revenue / GDP](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/GC.TAX.TOTL.GD.ZS?page=4). Equador seems like a fine answer at about 5%-6%. The only thing that makes this too broad is the "why", and possibly the length of time (World Bank data doesn't go back that far). Additionally @Chad, an increase in tax revenue / GDP of that sort wouldn't be infinite, it would just be the rate. If you tax people at 0% one year and 100% the next year, the increase is 100% (we aren't doing derivatives and figuring out the **rate** of increase)

Comment: @user1873 - But the why is the only thing on topic at Politics SE.  This is a history question at best in its current form.  And the Rate of increase was exactly what the original question asked for.

Comment: @Chad, the rate of increase was **not** exactly what [the original question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/revisions/4504/1) was asking for "I am interested in knowing about the **biggest increases** in **tax revenue as a percentage of the GDP** and how nations and governments achieved it." That is an increase, not the rate of increase.

Comment: @user1873 - We can disagree on this.  The question is still off topic and too broad.

Comment: @user1873 What if you taxed them at 0% at the beginning of the year, then 50% during the middle of the year, and then at 100% at the end of the year and onward.  That scenario is still described as "0% one year and 100% the next year", but our answer has changed from 100% being the biggest increase, to 50% being the biggest increase.  And that's only the result of a difference in framing

Comment: @SamIam Why is the question still on hold?

Comment: @drake because you haven't convinced me that it's not too broad

Comment: @SamIam Have you read user1873's and my edits? You have not tell me why you think it admits more than one valid answer.

Comment: @drake [Oh yes, I have told you why it's too broad](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/why-is-this-question-on-hold/1462#1462)